# Make inference on parameter $\lambda$ in Box-Cox transformation by MLE method

Tags: st.statistics

The original form of the Box-Cox transformation, as appeared in
their 1964 paper, takes the following form: $$y(\lambda )=\begin{cases}\frac{y^{\lambda}-1}{\lambda}, & \lambda \neq 0\\ \log(y), & \lambda =0. \end{cases}$$ The main objective in the analysis of Box-Cox transformation
model is to make inference on the transformation parameter $\lambda$, and
Box and Cox (1964) considered two approaches.The first approach is to use the Maximum Likelihood method and the second approach is to use Bayesian method.

I've studied the paper "An Analysis of Transformations" by Box and Cox (1964) but unfortunately I didn't understand how to use the Maximum Likelihood method because I'm elementary in statistics. Is there a good reference that exaplains this method in a simple language? or Is there anyone who explains me how to make inference on $\lambda$? I want to learn them properl and use on my data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want inference on $\lambda$? It can be argued that $\lambda$ is not really a model parameter (it is indexing a family of models ...) and natural real-world hypothesis of interest would not involve $\lambda$. See  https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/pubs/AOS023.pdf

Comment: Dear @kjetilbhalvorsen , Thanks very much for the comment and the link. Actually, I want to understand how to make inference on $\lambda$ with MLE: https://www.ime.usp.br/~abe/lista/pdfm9cJKUmFZp.pdf . You knwo, I'm a student in pure mathematics and I have to know the mathematics behind everything that I want to use. I've found some notes about how to use R software to transforn the data but I want to know how to make inefernce on $\lambda $ with MLE theoretically.